# Wine: Application requires security update xxxxxx to be installed

Tags: software-installation, updates, xubuntu, wine, 22.04

This is what I get when I run `GoogleDriveSetup.exe` on Ubuntu 22.04 with Wine.
I use Wine 6.0.3.

[image]

Comment: check https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28866 . You probably need to configure WINEPREFIX and WINEARCH.

Comment: I do not have a solution but I have an amazing suggestion. You can use KIO GDrive to access the Google drive in Ubuntu. KIO GDirve is used to transfer files from your Google drive to your computer and also to copy files from your computer to the google drive.
To install and use KIO GDrive in Ubuntu 22.04: https://itslinuxfoss.com/install-use-kio-gdrive-ubuntu/ Thanks